# search mongoDB documents by ObjectID in php

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, php-mongodb

How to search for documents using objectId using mongoDB driver.

Imported MongoDB\Client

Documentation says to use `['_id' => new MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID( idToken )]`, but there is no presence of the class mentioned in the driver

Comment: http://php.net/manual/de/class.mongodb-bson-objectid.php

Comment: Looks like you are using legacy MongoDB\Client. Do you see MongoId ?

Comment: No i don't see anything like that ... m just importing MongoDB\Client..

Comment: Import MongoDB\BSON Do you see that ?

Comment: No .. i dont see that ..Any idea on how to do that ?? required the package using composer

Comment: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-library/tree/master/src

Comment: Try the instructions from [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/current/tutorial/install-php-library/). Are you installing driver manually ?

Comment: m installing the same way they told using composer .. working on it for months but never searched using ObjectID .. the class they told isn't there in the librarry

Comment: able to solve it using the same class documented in the docs using the extension